# Is this a mistake in Volume 1 of Apostol's Calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am referring to page 112, near the bottom. Apostol claims that

> Note that Cavalieri's principle has been stated in the form of inequalities. If $a(S \cap F) = a(T \cap F)$ for every plane $F$ perpendicular to a given line, we may apply Axiom $5$ twice to deduce $v(S) \le v(T)$ and $v(T) \le v(S)$, and hence $v(T) = v(S).$

Specifically, I am wondering about the “apply Axiom $5$ twice” part. Here is Axiom $5$:

> 5. Choice of scale. Every box $B$ is in $\mathscr{A}$. If the edges of $B$ have lengths $a,b,$ and $c$ then $v(B) = abc.$

But right above it is Axiom 4, which states Cavalieri's principle:

> 4. Cavalieri's principle. If $S$ and $T$ are two Cavalieri solids in $\mathscr{A}$ with $a(S \cap F) \le a(T \cap F)$ for every plane $F$ perpendicular to a given line, then $v(S) \le v(T).$

If it is not a mistake, then I am confused on how to deduce the aforementioned claim using Axiom $5$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly a mistake and supposed to refer to "Cavalieri's principle" instead of "Axiom 5". So many decades of computing already, and people inexplicably still have not learnt to use auto-numbering?